# Using Resource Governor with SQL Agent Jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, resource-governor

I'm trying to setup Resource Governor for limiting IOPS for processes running using SQL agent jobs. The classifier function is set to identify a particular login (any spid that is running using that login should use the resource group it is assigned to). I then added `EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'ResourceGovernerUser'` within the job, but I cannot get it to work and it falls back to the default pool because the jobs are `'EXECUTED AS 'ServiceAccount''`. Although if I look at the active processes using `sp_WhoisActive`, the login name is displayed as `'ResourceGovernerUser'` instead of the Service Account. So I modified the classifier function to use the Service Account and then it just worked. I verified this using the perfmon counters `'Disk Read IO/Sec'` and `'Disk Write IO/Sec'` under `'Resource Pool Stats'` object.

The question is - how do I get Resource Governor to use a login other than the Service Account (when used with agent jobs)? I do have some untested ugly ideas like - running the jobs using a CmdExec or PowerShell proxy. If anyone has come across a similar situation or has any better ideas, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

```
    --Example Setup:
    USE [master]
    GO

    CREATE RESOURCE POOL [SqlJobPool] WITH( 
            min_iops_per_volume=1, 
            max_iops_per_volume=5000); 
    GO

    CREATE WORKLOAD GROUP [IOGroup] 
        USING [SqlJobPool];
    GO

    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_LimitedIO]()
    RETURNS SYSNAME WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @grp SYSNAME;

            IF SUSER_NAME() = N'ResourceGovernerUser' -- When this is set to the Service Account, it works
                BEGIN
                    SET @grp = N'IOGroup';
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @grp = N'default';
                END
            RETURN @grp;
        END
    GO

    ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR with (CLASSIFIER_FUNCTION = dbo.fn_LimitedIO);
    ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE;
    GO 

    --Within the Agent job
    EXECUTE AS Login = 'ResourceGovernerUser'
    EXECUTE SomeSQLStuff
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resource governor classifier functions only run during the  Login process.  Impersonation via `EXECUTE AS` does not trigger the classifier function.  `EXECUTE AS` is how SQL Server Agent runs jobs in the context of another login or user.

Specifying the `Run As ...` user or modifying the `Job Owner` does not change how SQL Server Agent logs into SQL Server.  The only way I can get SQL Server agent jobs to run in a specific resource group with a classifier function that looks only at the user name is to put the SQL Server Agent *Service Account* into it's own resource group.

Since testing is a great way to understand what is really happening, I've created a small test-bed.  Don't run this on a production system since it will modify the resource group configuration.

This creates the classifier function, and several resource groups attached to a test resource pool:

```
USE master;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnDummyClassifier()
RETURNS sysname
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @GroupName sysname = NULL;
    IF SUSER_SNAME() = 'DOMAIN\USER'
        SET @GroupName = N'AgentServiceAccountGroup';

    IF SUSER_SNAME() = 'ResourceGovernorTestLogin'
        SET @GroupName = N'ResourceGovernorTestLoginGroup';

    IF SUSER_SNAME() = 'ResourceGovernorTestUser'
        SET @GroupName = N'ResourceGovernorTestUserGroup';

    IF @GroupName IS NULL
        SET @GroupName =  N'default';

    RETURN @GroupName;
END
GO
CREATE RESOURCE POOL TestPool
WITH (MAX_CPU_PERCENT = 10); 
CREATE WORKLOAD GROUP AgentServiceAccountGroup 
WITH (
      group_max_requests=0
    , importance=Medium
    , request_max_cpu_time_sec=0
    , request_max_memory_grant_percent=25
    , request_memory_grant_timeout_sec=0
    , max_dop=0
    )
USING TestPool;
CREATE WORKLOAD GROUP ResourceGovernorTestLoginGroup 
WITH (
      group_max_requests=0
    , importance=Medium
    , request_max_cpu_time_sec=0
    , request_max_memory_grant_percent=25
    , request_memory_grant_timeout_sec=0
    , max_dop=0
    )
USING TestPool;
CREATE WORKLOAD GROUP ResourceGovernorTestUserGroup 
WITH (
      group_max_requests=0
    , importance=Medium
    , request_max_cpu_time_sec=0
    , request_max_memory_grant_percent=25
    , request_memory_grant_timeout_sec=0
    , max_dop=0
    )
USING TestPool;
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR WITH (CLASSIFIER_FUNCTION = [dbo].[fnDummyClassifier]);
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Here we'll create a login, and allow it to `VIEW SERVER STATE` so we can tell which resource group the session has been assigned to.

```
CREATE LOGIN ResourceGovernorTestLogin
WITH PASSWORD = '!NnrtiHummusPlenumPoodle2'
    , DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = us_english
    , CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF
    , CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
GRANT VIEW SERVER STATE TO ResourceGovernorTestLogin;
GO
```

This creates a SQL Server Agent job where the "owner" is set to the login we just created.  Since the login is not a member of sysadmin, SQL Server agent will run this job in the context of that login.

```
DECLARE @JobID uniqueidentifier;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name = 'TestResourceGovernorJob'
    , @enabled = 1
    , @description = 'Tests resource governor classification'
    , @start_step_id = 1
    , @owner_login_name = 'ResourceGovernorTestLogin'
    , @job_id = @JobID OUTPUT;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id = @JobID, @step_id = 1, @step_name = 'Step1'
    , @subsystem = 'TSQL'
    , @command = 'SELECT '''';
SELECT UserName = CONVERT(nvarchar(30), SUSER_SNAME())
    , [SYSTEM_USER] = CONVERT(nvarchar(30), SYSTEM_USER)
    , [SESSION_USER] = CONVERT(nvarchar(30), SESSION_USER)
    , [ORIGINAL_LOGIN] = CONVERT(nvarchar(30), ORIGINAL_LOGIN())
    , WorkloadGroup = CONVERT(nvarchar(30), wg.name)
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests der
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_resource_governor_workload_groups wg ON der.group_id = wg.group_id
WHERE der.session_id = @@SPID;'
    , @flags = 4 --write step output into msdb.dbo.sysjobstephistory
    , @on_success_action = 1;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @JobID, @server_name = N'(LOCAL)';
/*
    Call SQL Server Agent via msdb.dbo.sp_notify_job 
    which in turn calls msdb.dbo.xp_notify_job.
    The SQL Server Agent executable logs into the
    SQL Server instance using the service account,
    then performs an "EXECUTE AS ..." to run
    job step(s).
*/
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_id = @JobID;
GO

WAITFOR DELAY N'00:00:01';
DECLARE @msg nvarchar(max);
SELECT @msg = sjh.message
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory sjh
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj ON sjh.job_id = sj.job_id
WHERE sj.name = 'TestResourceGovernorJob'
    AND sjh.step_id = 1;
PRINT (N'');
PRINT (@msg);
PRINT (N'');
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = 'TestResourceGovernorJob';
GO
```

The results from the msdb history table for the above job:

```
Job 'TestResourceGovernorJob' started successfully.

Executed as user: ResourceGovernorTestLogin. 
-

(1 rows(s) affected)
UserName                       SYSTEM_USER                    SESSION_USER                   ORIGINAL_LOGIN                 WorkloadGroup
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
ResourceGovernorTestLogin      ResourceGovernorTestLogin      guest                          DOMAIN\USER                    AgentServiceAccountGroup
(1 rows(s) affected).  The step succeeded.
```

Next, we'll create a user for the login, and run a new version of the job using the `Run As` option in the advanced properties of the SQL Server Job Step.

```
CREATE USER ResourceGovernorTestUser
FOR LOGIN ResourceGovernorTestLogin;

DECLARE @JobID uniqueidentifier;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name = 'TestResourceGovernorJob'
    , @enabled = 1
    , @description = 'Tests resource governor classification'
    , @start_step_id = 1
    , @owner_login_name = 'ResourceGovernorTestLogin'
    , @job_id = @JobID OUTPUT;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id = @JobID, @step_id = 1, @step_name = 'Step1'
    , @subsystem = 'TSQL'
    , @database_name = 'master'
    , @database_user_name = 'ResourceGovernorTestUser'
    , @command = 'SELECT '''';
SELECT UserName = CONVERT(nvarchar(30), SUSER_SNAME())
    , [SYSTEM_USER] = CONVERT(nvarchar(30), SYSTEM_USER)
    , [SESSION_USER] = CONVERT(nvarchar(30), SESSION_USER)
    , [ORIGINAL_LOGIN] = CONVERT(nvarchar(30), ORIGINAL_LOGIN())
    , WorkloadGroup = CONVERT(nvarchar(30), wg.name)
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests der
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_resource_governor_workload_groups wg ON der.group_id = wg.group_id
WHERE der.session_id = @@SPID;'
    , @flags = 4 --write step output into msdb.dbo.sysjobstephistory
    , @on_success_action = 1;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @JobID, @server_name = N'(LOCAL)';
/*
    Call SQL Server Agent via msdb.dbo.sp_notify_job 
    which in turn calls msdb.dbo.xp_notify_job.
    The SQL Server Agent executable logs into the
    SQL Server instance using the service account,
    then performs an "EXECUTE AS ..." to run
    job step(s).
*/
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_id = @JobID;
GO

WAITFOR DELAY N'00:00:01';
DECLARE @msg nvarchar(max);
SELECT @msg = sjh.message
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory sjh
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj ON sjh.job_id = sj.job_id
WHERE sj.name = 'TestResourceGovernorJob'
    AND sjh.step_id = 1;
PRINT (N'');
PRINT (@msg);
PRINT (N'');
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name = 'TestResourceGovernorJob';

DROP USER ResourceGovernorTestUser;
GO
```

The output from that run of the job:

```
Job 'TestResourceGovernorJob' started successfully.

Executed as user: ResourceGovernorTestLogin. 
-

(1 rows(s) affected)
UserName                       SYSTEM_USER                    SESSION_USER                   ORIGINAL_LOGIN                 WorkloadGroup
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
ResourceGovernorTestLogin      ResourceGovernorTestLogin      ResourceGovernorTestUser       DOMAIN\USER                    AgentServiceAccountGroup
(1 rows(s) affected).  The step succeeded.
```

This cleans up the resource governor configuration, and drops the classifier function and the login.

```
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR WITH (CLASSIFIER_FUNCTION = NULL);
DROP WORKLOAD GROUP AgentServiceAccountGroup;
DROP WORKLOAD GROUP ResourceGovernorTestUserGroup;
DROP WORKLOAD GROUP ResourceGovernorTestLoginGroup;
DROP RESOURCE POOL TestPool;
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE;
DROP FUNCTION dbo.fnDummyClassifier
DROP LOGIN ResourceGovernorTestLogin;
GO
```

In both result sets above, you can see the Resource Governor classifier function put each job into the `AgentServiceAccountGroup` group; this is because the SQL Server Agent initially logs into SQL Server using the Service Account used when SQL Server Agent starts up.